# Discord.js Exception embed author name has to be a string only accurse on Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, discord.js

Hello Im having an utterly bizzare issue

Basically im currently trying to make an embed

```
        const error_embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#c00be0')
        .setTitle("To use this command please mention a user")
        .setAuthor({ name: msg.author.tag + ' ', iconURL: msg.author.avatarURL() })
```

This is my current code

Now something utterly bizzare happens

Whenever im testing this code on my local machine it works perfectly without an issue

However whenever I deploy the code on Heroku it for some reason fails with the exception

```
MessageEmbed author name must be a string
```

If you dont know a lot about heroku please note that

Heroku uses the same node engine that I am using

Heroku uses the same discord.js version I am using

I have tried a few things to troubleshoot the issue

I first attempted to make the name a normal non variable string

this failed again

I also attempted to convert the content of the variable to string via the string.toString() method

Please note that this issue is for some reason exclusive to heroku

The code is the same

The modules are the same

The node version is the same

and it works perfectly on my pc

Comment: You can try `name:  \`${msg.author.tag}\`` to convert it to a `string`

Comment: @新Acesyyy Even if `msg.author.tag` is not a string, OP already converted it to a string using `+ '  '`

Comment: Wait, using that way making the `msg.author.tag` as a string?

Comment: I've only ever seen `' ' + <number>`, does the other way around work aswell?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention the ' ' + msg.author.tag was another attempt of mine to try to solve the issue but it doesnt seems to work as well

Comment: @新Acesyyy Yes, concatenating a string with any other data type will result in a string. I've got a codepen link where you can see how it works: https://codepen.io/zsoltime/pen/bGvpQYm

Comment: @Furious Have you done some basic debugging? Have you checked the `typeof` and the value of `msg.author.tag`? What's your discord.js version?

Comment: Can you log directly in the `verifyString` method of `node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Util.js`?

Comment: how do I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
let author = {}
author.name = msg.author.tag.toString()
author.iconURL = msg.author.avatarURL()
```

```
  const error_embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#c00be0')
        .setTitle("To use this command please mention a user")
        .setAuthor(author)
```

Making an empty object and adding values is usually less buggy than having an object with the keys and values inside. Also, try using `.toString()`

Answer (score 1):

It looks as youre trying to pass an object as a string! That constructor requires the `setAuthor` property to be a string. You can instead try to do

```
const author;
author = msg.author.tag.toString();
```

Hope this works for ya!